# Unable to find serial ports

Tags: java, serial-port

Using Rxtx API.

I am 100% sure there is a serial port available. On Debian, I can see `/dev/ttyUSB3` exists when the device is connected.

Tried running `getPortIdentifiers()` and got nothing when I tried iterating over the hashset

```
CommPortIdentifier portIdentifier = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifier("/dev/ttyUSB3");
```

Also did not work. I got:

> Exception Caused by: gnu.io.NoSuchPortException

What am I doing wrong? I am fairly sure rxtx was set up correctly.

Comment: Is there a permissions issue? Try running `sudo chmod 666 /dev/ttyUSB3` first

Comment: Don't think that helped. Still turned up nothing in the hashset and threw NoSuchPortException.

Comment: thats strange.. Maybe its a setup issue. I've had success using [this library](https://github.com/NeuronRobotics/nrjavaserial): com.neuronrobotics:nrjavaserial:3.11.0 which is an rxtx fork with all the binaries baked in.

Comment: Working on a company project as an intern so I would mess around with dependencies only as a last resort. Any other theories why it isn't working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is with how RXTX defines ports.  By default, it will only look for certain serial ports(on Linux, `/dev/ttySX`).  There are several options you have to fix this:

1. Set the `gnu.io.rxtx.SerialPorts` property when you start Java(either on the command line, or through code.  See the [Rxtx documentation](http://rxtx.qbang.org/wiki/index.php/FAQ#RXTX_does_not_find_my_device.2C_what.27s_wrong.3F) for more details)
2. Use a different serial port library that lets you select serial ports manually.

For #2, the following are libraries that I know of:

- [RXTX](http://rxtx.qbang.org/wiki/index.php/Main_Page)
- [JSSC](https://github.com/scream3r/java-simple-serial-connector)
- [PureJavaComm](http://www.sparetimelabs.com/purejavacomm/purejavacomm.php)
- [JavaSerial](https://github.com/rm5248/JavaSerial) (disclaimer: this is my library)

Comment: Sir, you are a living legend. Thank you so much. #1 resolved my problem.

Comment: Think I spoke a bit too soon. Worked once and now its back to NoSuchPortException.  One thing to note is that I just closed the program without calling .close(). I read a bit about this problem and one solution was to delete a file in /var/lock, but these are the only files, LCK..ttyO4  LCK..ttyO5 LCK..ttyUSB2  lockdev  subsys. Wondering why ttyUSB3 doesn't show up here. Any other ways to "unlock" the serial port?

Comment: @JerryLiu I don't know why the port would still be locked - it has been a while since I have used RXTX.  You may want to check `lsof` and see if anything else has the port open.